# PHP maximum execution time

Tags: php, apache, execution-time, mod-fcgid

In my Plesk 11, PHP 5.4.7. Apache/2.4.3 system, when I make cron jobs I get this error from error.log file.

```
[Tue Mar 19 21:33:18 2013] [warn] [client 88.44.55.66] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds
[Tue Mar 19 21:33:18 2013] [error] [client 88.44.55.66] Premature end of script headers: index.php
```

So I checked for execution time with this:

```
echo ini_get('max_execution_time');
```

I got this value: `1560000`

It doesn't seem a timeout problem but I get timeout error?

Answer for the future reference:
Edit `/etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf` file with vim.
Change `FcgidIOTimeout 45` to `FcgidIOTimeout 600`.
Restart Apache.
Then Fast CGI timeout will be solved.

Comment: If it's a cron job, it should be run by the system's `crond` using the PHP executable instead of the HTTP server.

Comment: @rid Unfortunately, many people end up writing the cron job to request a page with wget/curl.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a `mod_fcgid` timeout, not a PHP timeout. Take a look at the [`mod_fcgid` documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html) to find out how to change it, especially at [`FcgidIOTimeout`](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidiotimeout).

Comment: Just in case it helps anyone:
Increase the FcgidIOTimeout value in fcgid.conf and restart Apache.

CentOS: /etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf

Debian: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fcgid.conf

Comment: Correct for Internet Server Error with php + curl and error after exact 40 sec. For me, this was the correct answer. For CENTOS / RHE (7), you can find fcgid.conf here: /etc/httpd/conf.d. I need to add the following line to solve the Internal Server Error: FcgidIOTimeout 300

Answer (score 5):

Cron scripts if build correctly should not be run through apache. Your error shows that you are running into a timeout set by mod_fcgi.

Comment: Cron scripts if build correctly should not be run through apache. 

So where should we run cron scripts ??

Comment: @FoysalVai Via console, directory with something like `php /path/to/php/script.php`

Answer (score 1):

If you access it through http in your cronjob, then it will work as a webpage request and then it may be affected by apache timeout because apache is involved in the process. You can run the php script directly with an absolute path using php interpreter to bypass apache

Comment: You can run the php script directly with an absolute path using php interpreter to bypass apache


How can we do that ??